# C# NHibernate join problems

Tags: nhibernate

I may have possible mapped wrong, or something, NHibernate seems to be confusing to me, but when it works it is smooth. I have Google'd everything to this point and I am still learning NHibernate. I am trying to query an Address that has a accountId, which would  link to my AccountUser map, which has a userId that would link to my Usermap. I want to look up all the addresses with the user name of "joe". Anyone know how I would do this with my query? below is my maps, and query:

```
public AddressMap()
{
        Table("Address");
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.FirstName);
        Map(x => x.MiddleName);
        Map(x => x.LastName);
        Map(x => x.CompanyName);
        Map(x => x.Street);
        Map(x => x.City);
        Map(x => x.State);
        Map(x => x.AccountID);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        References(x => x.AccountUser);
}

public class AccountUserMap: ClassMap<AccountUser>
{
    public AccountUserMap()
    {
        Table("AccountUser");
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.UserId);
        Map(x => x.AccountID).Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.User);
    }
}

public UserMap()
{
        Table("User");
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
        Map(x => x.Name);
}

// non working query:
Address address = null;
User user = null;
AccountUser accountUser = null;
var query = session.QueryOver<Address>(() => address)
               .JoinQueryOver(x => x.AccountUser, () => accountUser)
               .Where(() => accountUser.AccountID == address.AccountID)
               .JoinQueryOver(y => y.User, () => user)
               .Where(() => user.Id == accountUser.UserId )
               .And(() => user.Name == "joe")
                .List()).ToList();
```

the error message isn't very helpful either...

> {"Invalid column name 'AccountUser_id'.\r\nInvalid column name
>   'User_id'.\r\nInvalid column name 'AccountUser_id'.\r\nInvalid column
>   name 'User_id'."}

there is nothing named with the underscore, so it must be something with NHibernate

Also, this SQL query below works, and is what I want to do:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
  [AddressID]
  ,[FirstName]
  ,[MiddleName]
  ,[LastName]
  FROM Address
  inner join AccountUser accountUser
  on AccountUser.AccountID = Address.AccountID
  inner join User user
  on user.UserID = accountUser.UserID
  where user.Name= 'joe'
```

Hopefully thats enough detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the property names do not match the database names you have to specify them in the mapping, for example:

```
Id(x => x.Id, "AddressID").GeneratedBy.Native();
```

or Fluent NHibernate will use its default naming convention for key columns.